# Passing a class from Livewire Component class to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Is it possible to pass a `ColumnChartModel` to the view in a livewire component? in my code below, `$columnChartModel` is defined in the livewire class but null in the view.

```php
    public function render()
    {
        $columnChartModel =
            (new ColumnChartModel())
                ->setTitle('Expenses by Type')
                ->addColumn('Food', 100, '#f6ad55')
                ->addColumn('Shopping', 200, '#fc8181')
                ->addColumn('Travel', 300, '#90cdf4');

        return view('livewire.report-daily-calls-by-hour', compact('columnChartModel'));
    }
```

I cannot pass it as a property, such as:

```php
public $columnChartModel;
```

because livewire does not support this as a property.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Adding data in the render method the way you're doing it means it won't be serialized by Livewire. This means it literally does not matter what you pass with the view. This should work fine. Are you certain you have a result before compacting it in to the view?